# Convert String in Array JQUERY

Tags: jquery, arrays, date, datetime

I have the data  array return of the server :

```
data.arr = [[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 17),1],[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 18),5],[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 19),2],[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 20),4]]

    [0] "[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 17),1]" String
    [1] "[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 18),5]" String
    [2] "[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 19),2]" String
    [3] "[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 20),4]" String
```

I need to pass only value to a function that recepeit an array[i,y], i need that stay following; i need to remove the "".

```
    [0] [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 17),1]
    [1] [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 18),5]
    [2] [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 19),2]
    [3] [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 20),4]
```

How to do it?

Comment: Have you tried using `eval()`?

Comment: `eval` is your friend, it's not evil at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> data.arr = [[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 17),1],[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 18),5],
> [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 19),2],[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 20),4]]
> ```

This code should already give you a timestamp value, but I am assuming you are asking about when it is treated as string so as suggested in comments, you can use eval to evaluate the string as Data Object.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.arr.length; i++) {
     data.arr[i] = [data.arr[i][0], eval(data.arr[i][1])];
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8eLEH/

Answer (score 0):

To remove "" from your string you can use following:

```
yourString.replace(/"/g, '');
```

Comment: I'm using an array , the values of the array i can't have the String.